# Как вставить переменную "i" из цикла for в html код на JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<div id="gallery">
</div>

function block() {
    let wrap = $("<div class='block'>")
    for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        wrap.clone().appendTo($("#gallery"));
    }
}
block();
```

Имеется функция, где на страницу в блок #gallery добавляется некоторое кол-во div с классом block. Как сделать, чтобы в каждый из этих div дополнительно добавлялась значение переменной "i" из цикла в span, т.е. счетчик этих div-ов? Что-то меня только получалось, что с каждым новым div остается предыдущее значение "i" и к нему добавляется следующее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function block() {
    let wrap = $("<div class='block'>")
    for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        let c = wrap.clone()
        $("<span>").text(i).appendTo(c)
        c.appendTo($("#gallery"));
    }
}
block();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
    function block() {
        for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            let wrap = $("<div class='block'>"+i+"</div>");
            wrap.appendTo($("#gallery"));
        }
    }
    block();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery">
</div>
```